# Checking if asset exists in Google Cloud Storage - cors error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-storage

I have some assets uploaded to Google Cloud Storage. On my client side I need to display them in conditional logic, ie. if there is Google Cloud Storage uploaded asset then show it, otherwise show something different. So before I'll put it to `img` tag in `src` attribute I need to check its existence. In order to do that I wanted to use axios (as I'm using axios in my project). The checking function for now looks like this (very simple):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(imageSource).then((response) => {
      console.log(response)
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }, []);
```

I used `useEffect` to check it at the beginning of lifecycle of the component.

For some reason though I'm getting cors error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'here goes file url' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

That's quite unexpected for me as I can indeed go to that link in the browser and download it with no hassle. Should I enable something on GCS platform or is there another way of checking an GCS asset existence?

Comment: You can't do XHR requests outside your domain, unless the endpoint you're calling accepts CORS requests. Generally, that's a bad idea to allow, so I doubt GCS allows that. This only goes for XHR, though, which is why you can access the URL in the browser or in regular HTML.

Answer (score 1):

According to what you mention, you still have not configured your CORS policy for your bucket. You can read more about how to do this [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors) and try again.

Let me know if it helps

Comment: Thank you for answering!  Generally, Stack Overflow prefers answers that do not depend on a link to an outside site.  Consider including the information that answers the question here and then reference the site you got it from.